# SQL selection based on two variables, exclusive of others

Tags: sql, database, select, subquery

I'm querying a table looking at three fields; unit_id, group_id, and service.

Each unit_id is unique, and has a single group_id and service associated with it.

I want to return group_id and service where all the units with that group_id have the same service. For instance, if i have:

```
unit_id    group_id    service
1          group_A     apple
2          group_B     orange
3          group_B     apple
4          group_A     apple
5          group_C     banana
```

I want it to return group_A and group_C, because all services in those group_ids are the same, whereas group_B has both orange and apple.

How do I write a SQL query that accomplishes that?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from your_table
where group_id in
(
  select group_id
  from your_table
  group by group_id
  having count(distinct service) = 1
)
```

Comment: @juergen_d Gotcha, that makes a lot of sense, thanks!